# Mixed Content: The page at 'https//siteurl' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 'http/siteurl''

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

although I am providing url with https , it's kept saying the following error :

[image]

my codes from script :

```
$.ajax({
  url: "https://www.aspireelearning.com/api/summitRegistration",
  type:"POST",
  data:{
    full_name:full_name,email:email, phone:phone, country:country, organization:organization, 
 profession : profession, check_conditions : check_conditions
    },
    success:function(data){

    if($.isEmptyObject(data.error)){
      $("#registration_error").removeClass('colorRed');
      $('#check_conditions').removeClass('checkboxBorder');
      $("#registration_error").text(data.success).addClass('colorGreen');
       getRegistrationNumber();
    }else{
      $('#registration_error').addClass('colorGreen');
      $('#registration_error').text(data.error).addClass('colorRed');
      $('#check_conditions').text(data.error).addClass('checkboxBorder');
       getRegistrationNumber();
    }
    
    },

  });
 });
```

middleware cors.php :

[image]

Code for getRegistrationNumber :

```
getRegistrationNumber();


function getRegistrationNumber(){

$.getJSON('https://www.url',function(data){
   var countNumber = parseInt(data.getCount);
   var addWith = 1566;

   var totalRegistered = countNumber+addWith;

   $(".registered-member-number").html(totalRegistered);
});
```

}

Comment: I think you need to post the contents of `getRegistrationNumber`, too

Comment: @ChrisHaas, sure I am editing the question with contents

Comment: @ChrisHaas, It kepts returning http, even if I change it by a different URL

Comment: you are hardcoding https::  in your javascript URL.  change it to HTTP